# Conditional output HTML in jsx

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am trying to change some jsx which at the moment simply loops and outputs jsx, When i try to change the loop to output based on a value in the array objects I get an error in the code as it dosent like how I am trying to output the html.

There is a value in the array called Group and if the group name is different from the last group name then output a label to show the new group name

What i have to start with is ..

```
<Container className="float-left">
{ 
    this.Store.SearchResults.map( template =>                       
    <TemplateCard
        key={template.Name}
        ....
    >                       
    { template.Name }
    </TemplateCard>)                    
}
</Container>
```

What I would like to do is...

```
<Container className="float-left">
{ 
    this.Store.SearchResults.map( template =>
    {
            var lastGroup;
            if(template.Group !== lastGroup ){
                    // output group name
                    <div>
                    <Label>{template.Group}</Label>
                    </div>
            }
    }                   
    <TemplateCard
        key={template.Name}
        ....
    >                       
    { template.Name }
    </TemplateCard>)                    
}
</Container>
```

This gives error.. - Unexpected token, expected ","

Comment: Do you need the `.map()` twice?

Comment: Not sure? Bit new to react so not sure what to do..

Comment: check this https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

Comment: Please post the complete container code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many issues with your code. 
Not sure if you need to use map twice for your use case, but since `.map()` should return a single element, you should wrap the whole thing in a [React Fragment](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html) and use it like -

```
this.Store.SearchResults.map( (template, index) =>
        {
            var lastGroup; // Make sure to initialize it with some value
            return (
             <React.Fragment key={index}>
              {template.Group !== lastGroup &&
                (<div>
                <Label>{template.Group}</Label>
                </div>)
              }
              <TemplateCard
                key={template.Name}
                ....
              >                       
                { template.Name }
              </TemplateCard>                  
            </React.Fragment>);
        }
```

More improvements / things to keep in mind -

1. Add a return statement inside `.map()` if doing operations before returning a JSX element.
2. Add a key to the element inside `.map()`.
3. Double check your brackets if you're missing something. Can be a bit messy if you're new to JSX

Comment: Thanks for your comments and code.  I will have a try with this. There is a return but it is higher up and was removed to keep simple. The key is template name.

Comment: The point is to wrap it in a React Fragment so that it returns a single top level element from `map`. You can give it any key you wish

Answer (score 0):

You can use a ternary operator which will render the div if the condition is true and render null otherwise:

```
{template.Group !== lastGroup ?
    <div>
        <Label>{template.Group}</Label>
    </div>
: null}
```

Comment: Thanks, this gives same error... Unexpected token, expected ","

Comment: It is perfectly fine to use `var...` inside `map`, just with a curly brace syntax

Answer (score 0):

All, thanks for your help.

I could not get this to work, as Jayakumar said I probably needed to post more code. Anyway I have managed to resolve a different way for now. Resolved by having separate arrays and having a new section below this one, This may come back as an issue later but for now it will do.

Thanks